# Is it undefined in Rust to temporarily swap uninitialized values into a vector?

Tags: vector, rust, swap, undefined-behavior

Suppose I have a vector, `v: Vec<T>` with length 5 and capacity 10.  Does the following invoke undefined behavior?

```
let p = v.as_mut_ptr(); 
unsafe {
    std::mem::swap(p, p.offset(5));
    std::mem::swap(p.offset(5), p);
}
```

Comment: A very well defined behaviour: Syntax error! I think you missed a couple semicolons on the unsafe block... :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is undefined. From Section 6.1.3.2.3 of the [Rust Reference](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#behavior-considered-undefined):

> The following is a list of behavior which is forbidden in all Rust code, including within unsafe blocks and unsafe functions. Type checking provides the guarantee that these issues are never caused by safe code.
>
> - ...
> - Reads of undef (uninitialized) memory
> - ...

`p.offset(5)` is undefined memory and you have to read it to be able to swap it.

Of course, I don't really see the point to your question, as even if it were defined, the operation would be a no-op. I suspect that this is an artifact of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and that you have an actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The actual problem is I want to take two sorted vectors v and w and without creating a new vector (although I may reserve more space for v) merge w into v. It would be nice if the type doesn't necessarily need to implement Default.

Comment: Don't swap with locations you can't safely read from. If the location is uninitialized, you can `ptr::write` to it, but not swap with it.